# Create wrapper around plugin in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using a plugin in React Native that doesn't contain all of the props that I need.

Ideally I'd like to modify the library and create a pull request, but I don't have time to wait for approvals.

How can I create a wrapper around the library in order to modify certain files?